# Arraylist of arraylists in JTable

Tags: java, swing, static, compilation, jtable

I have a class called Database with an arrayList called applicants. Each record in the arrayList applicants is an arrayList of applicant details. (So Database class contains an arrayList of arrayLists).

I also have a class called GUI which contains a JTable:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Application number",
                                "Program",
                                "Name",
                                "Date",
                                "Accepted?"};

Object[][] data = {Database.applicants};
```

Whenever i compile it says: "Non static variable applicants cannot be referenced from a static context"

Any pointers on what i may need to do would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use static methods and variables.

Comment: I've now created an instance of class Database in my GUI class. and changed Object[][] data = {database.applicants}; It now says "incompatible types" - Would i need to convert the arrayList to a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would i need to convert the arrayList to a List?

You are trying to assign an ArrayList to an Array, so you would need to copy the data from the ArrayList to the Array.

Or another option is to create a custom TableModel that uses an ArrayList to hold the data for the model. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error

```
public static List applicants ...
```

But that might not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try considering Vector's; they're more dynamic, and you can add rows of String[] or List to them.
try this:

```
public class Database {

    private static Vector columnsName;
    private static Vector data;

    public static Vector getColumnsNames() {
        if (null == columnsName) {
            columnsName = new Vector();
            columnsName.add("Program Number");
            columnsName.add("Program Name");
            columnsName.add("Program Date");
        }
        return columnsName;
    }

    public static Vector getData() {
        if (null == data) {
            populateData();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static void populateData() {
        data = new Vector();
        String[] firstRow = {
            "22", "Program", "Name", "12/12/2012", "yes"
        };
        data.add(firstRow);
    }
}
```

then from the GUI, you can prepare the model:

```
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(Database.getColumnsNames(), Database.getData()));
```